# Display logo on the same line as user login

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with this for a while now and about to throw in the towel.
What im trying to do is display the logo in float-left and the user welcome in float-left in the same line. instead of on different lines.
here is the code from my stylesheet.. please help

```
header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this CSS, but the HTML structure would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Display: inline-block;
```

On both the logo and the user login elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove `float`, use

```
display:inline-block;
```

for both elements(logo and user welcome).

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand without markup. Anyways from my interpretation you need this.

```
   Markup 

  <div class="logo">
    <img class="place-left" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQf2S3rAr9N1AonEHJ4MyamBQPzlz_1wledD4A0GdbNzO6Xw-Qy" />
    <div class=""> Bugatti welcomes you</div>
 </div>


  Styles

 .place-left {
        float: left;
 }

 .logo {
      height: 40px;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
 }

 .logo img {
       height: 40px;
       width: 40px;
 }

 .logo .message {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50px;
       top: 10px;
 }
```